# How do I return the most sold item given a month and a year?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I need to be able to return the most sold item (and the quantity sold) given a month and a year.

For example, if in a month:

a) order 23: 2 cakes, 5 cupcakes

b) order 21: 3 cupcakes

Then I'd need it to return 5 cupcakes.

How do I do this?

This is the model:

```
class Food(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
   quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.name

class Order(models.Model):
   food = models.ManyToManyField('Food', related_name='order', blank=True)
   date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   
   def __str__(self):
       return self.food
```

Ths is the serializer:

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
   class Meta:
       model = Order
       fields = '__all__'


class FoodSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

   class Meta:
       model = Food
       fields = '__all__'
```

This is my view, for now it's just very simple:

```
class OrderView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Order.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer
```

Comment: Can you add the related view since that's where it's supposed to happen.

Comment: @Guillaume I added it but there is not much in it.

Comment: where are you saving your month and year of the order placed?

Comment: @Neeraj I hadn't realized I didn't type it. I added it now, it's on the order model.

Comment: Alright, so when do you want to return most sold item? Will that be a separate view ?

Comment: @Neeraj Yes, I should make a different view for that since I also want to return client with most purchases so it'd be a different one.

Comment: @Neeraj in a type of pseudo code it'd be something like this: class MostSoldItemView():
    given month_and_year:
 return food.max(['name','quantity'])

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the data using query params in your view and then in serializer you can specify whatever data you want to show from that filtered queryset.

[DRF-Filter by Query Params](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-query-parameters)

[Django doc for month and year filter on queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/) (Search for month and year)

Your code structure would be somewhat like this:

```
MostSoldItemView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = 
    
    def get_query_set(self):
        queryset = Order.objects.all()
        month = self.request.query_params.get('month')
        year = self.request.query_params.get('year')
        filter_params = {}
        if month:
            filter_params['date__month'] = month
        if year:
            filter_params['date__year'] = year

        queryset.filter(**filter_params).all()
        return queryset
```

Your api call would have : `api/orders?month=11&year=2020`  as mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: I did that but I don't have a way to input the month and the year in the view, how should I do that?

Comment: You mean query params? @satoru in the url?

Comment: I mean that once I'm in the url, I need the user to be able to input a year or a month so I can get the result. For now I only have a list with the date and the order data.

Comment: Yes request params are sent in the url based on user inputs. You'll find many questions and articles on how to send request params from front end. For backend testing you can do it using postman. @satoru

Comment: Do you know how I can try it in the terminal?

Comment: You cannot test an api call on terminal @satoru